# How to create a database in Oracle8 Lite with Developer 2000?

Tags: oracle

I am new in Oracle. I install Oracle 8 Lite with Developer 2000. Now I want to create a database for me. For that I open Oracle8 Navigator and Create a database which user is system. But in Oracle SQL*Plus I can not communicate with the database. Or even after creating a table using Oracle8 Navigator I can't alter the table.

Please tell me how can I alter my table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Creating and Managing the Database for a Mobile Client"
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12095_01/doc.10303/e12089/admdb.htm#BDCBEGFI

Oracle Database Lite Mobile Server, provides integrated and complete middle-tier infrastructure to enable enterprise mobile strategies.

It is a specialized solution! You may still need a regular version? For example, Oracle Database 10g Express Edition, you can find it at oracle.com